# Is there such thing as a "asynchronous trigger" in DB2?

Tags: database, db2

What I want to know is whether it is possible for my program to insert something to a staging table, and have a trigger to run asynchronously on that piece of data.
The procedure the trigger is running could be a time consuming process, that's why I wanted to run it asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of operation, you could program a cron, and you it at specific times.
You can also use the TaskCenter (which is deprecated since version 9.x) and you can trigger the process whenever you want, or when a condition has been reached.

Anyway, you have to be more clear about the necessity of begin asynchronous.
Does the table with acquire many locks? does the process with use a lot of CPU? does the table is used in parallel by other processes?